# How to optimize this query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I optimize query in `SQL Server 2008`?

Here is my Query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        ListName ,
        ( SELECT    COUNT(id)
          FROM      tbl_SurveyAssign
          WHERE     ListName = a.ListName
                    AND UserName IN (
                    SELECT  UserName
                    FROM    tbl_Panelist
                    WHERE   tbl_Panelist.Subscribe = '1'
                            AND tbl_Panelist.Pending = '0'
                            AND tbl_Panelist.UserName IN (
                            SELECT  UserName
                            FROM    tbl_PanelistActivity
                            WHERE   tbl_PanelistActivity.ActivityDate > ( GETDATE()
                                                          - 180 ) ) )
        ) AS Active ,
        ( SELECT    COUNT(id)
          FROM      tbl_SurveyAssign
          WHERE     ListName = a.ListName
                    AND UserName IN (
                    SELECT  UserName
                    FROM    tbl_Panelist
                    WHERE   tbl_Panelist.Subscribe = '1'
                            AND tbl_Panelist.Pending = '1' )
        ) AS Pending ,
        ( SELECT    COUNT(id)
          FROM      tbl_SurveyAssign
          WHERE     ListName = a.ListName
                    AND UserName IN (
                    SELECT  UserName
                    FROM    tbl_Panelist
                    WHERE   tbl_Panelist.Subscribe = '0'
                            AND tbl_Panelist.Pending = '0' )
        ) AS UnSubscribe ,
        ( SELECT    COUNT(id)
          FROM      tbl_SurveyAssign
          WHERE     ListName = a.ListName
                    AND UserName IN (
                    SELECT  UserName
                    FROM    tbl_Panelist
                    WHERE   tbl_Panelist.Subscribe = '1'
                            AND tbl_Panelist.Pending = '0'
                            AND tbl_Panelist.UserName NOT IN (
                            SELECT  UserName
                            FROM    tbl_PanelistActivity
                            WHERE   tbl_PanelistActivity.ActivityDate > ( GETDATE()
                                                          - 180 ) ) )
        ) AS Inactive ,
        ( SELECT    COUNT(id)
          FROM      tbl_SurveyAssign
          WHERE     ListName = a.ListName
        ) AS Total ,
        ( SELECT    COUNT(id)
          FROM      tbl_SurveyAssign
          WHERE     ListName = a.ListName
                    AND UserName NOT IN ( SELECT    UserName
                                          FROM      tbl_Panelist )
        ) AS NotMember
FROM    tbl_SurveyAssign a
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please provide the execution plan for this query.

Comment: Would you provide the table structure and some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the data, indexes etc and looking on the execution plan I would say there is two ways of making the query easier for the SQL server to process.

**Simple soluiotn.**
If you doing SQL queries inside the select part, the server is likely to make the same query for each row in tbl_SurveyAssign.

if you for each query making a query groped by listname and (`select listname, count(*) from xxxxx group by listname`) and joining in the result, the server just needs to makeing one query for each column. But it also depends if hte content of tbl_SurveyAssign always contains all list rows...

**More advanced**
At a quick glance it looks like you should be able to make this query with just one or two queries using joins. If you for exemple using tbl_SurveyAssign as a main table and to a left join with tbl_Panelist using username grouping on list name, you could do a count on tbl_PanelList you should get the number of members. From that you can calculate NotMembers but substracting form count(*) (this will skip a `Not In(` that is quite heavy.

Someting like this

`select a.listname, count() Total, count() - count(b.username) NonMembers, 
sum(case when b.Subscribe = '0' and b.Pending = '0' then 1 else 0 end) Unsubscribed, 
sum(case when b.Subscribe = '1' and b.Pending = '1' then 1 else 0 end) Pending 
from tbl_SurveyAssign a
left outer join tbl_PanelList b on a.username = b.username`

You shold also be able to do a grouping query calculating the pending,active and unsubscribed just once.

if you grouping the activity by username and doing a max on the activity date you should be able to calculate the activity in one query as well.

`select a.listname, count() Total, count() - count(b.username) NonMembers, 
sum(case when b.Subscribe = '0' and b.Pending = '0' then 1 else 0 end) Unsubscribed, 
sum(case when b.Subscribe = '1' and b.Pending = '1' then 1 else 0 end) Pending, 
sum(case when b.Subscribe = '1' and b.Pending = '0' and act.DaysSinceLastActivity < 180  then 1 else 0 end) Active, 
sum(case when b.Subscribe = '1' and b.Pending = '0' and act.DaysSinceLastActivity >= 180  then 1 else 0 end) Inactive 
from tbl_SurveyAssign a
left outer join tbl_PanelList b on a.username = b.username
left outer join 
(
   select UserName, DateDiff(day, max(ActivityDate), GetDate()) DaysSinceLastActivity from tbl_PanelistActivity group by UserName
) act on a.username = act.username`

Something like that. Keep in mind that its not tested in anyway, and I am quit sure I have misspelled a keyword or two.. But it will give you much less code.. and I think it is more readable as well. AND if there still is a performance issue, you will have a much smaller activity plan to dig in to...

I hope that helps you!